# Transcendental proofs vs. Irrational proofs

Tags: irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Why are proofs of the transcendence of certain numbers usually harder than irrationality proofs of those same numbers (for example, Lindemann's proof of the transcendence of pi vs. Niven's proof of the irrationality of pi?)

Comment: Maybe because transcendence is a more complex concept than irrationality?

Answer (score 5):

Proving a number irrational
only involves showing that
the assumption that the number is rational
leads to a contradiction.

In other words, the number
cannot be the root of a linear equation
with integer coefficients.

To prove that a number is transcendental,
you must show that
the assumption that the number is a root
of $any$ polynomial of $any$ degree
with integer coefficients
leads to a contradiction.
This is far more difficult.

This is why
the Greeks were able to show that
$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational
(this can be done using only geometry, not algebra),
while it took until 1844
for the existence of transcendental numbers
to be proved by Liouville.
Hermite proved $e$ was transcendental in 1873,
Cantor proved that
almost all numbers are transcendental
(by showing that the algebraic numbers formed a countable set),
Lindeman proved that
$\pi$ was transcendental in 1882,
and so on.

Other names worthy of study are
 Weierstrass, Hilbert,
 Gelfond, Schneider,
and Baker.

Comment: Is the proof for transcendence far more difficult because, without a proof, there could potentially be a polynomial with integer coefficients that had as a root, the number in question (such as pi or e)? So it would be harder to prove that for ALL integer-coefficient polynomials, none of then had a root corresponding to the number in question?